# Ajax call to express route not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am trying to make an ajax call from one of my javascript files to an express route within my Node.js application, note that the javascript file is also part of the same Node.js application.

The issue I am having is that the data passed to the route is always empty. I can see that the route is being called because my console.log shows an object in the req but that object is empty.

Here is my code for the ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/match',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: "test",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Successfully saved the matched beans to the user.");
        }
    }).done(function ( ) {
        console.log("OK");
    }).fail(function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```

And my route looks like this:

```
router.post("/match", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
   console.log("Route Test1: " + req.body);
   console.log("Route Test2: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

In the first console.log of the route I get `Route Test1: [object Object]` and for the second console.log I get `Route Test2: {}` .

How do I access the data "test" which I passed to the route?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @Phil thanks! That returns 'undefined'. I actually have a JSON object which I need to pass as the data, but i simplified it to just "test" when I started having issues. Any other ideas?

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer. Are you using `body-parser` with `app.use(bodyParser.json())`?

Comment: @Phil yes I am, I have the following line in my app.js app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

Comment: You know `urlencoded` does not cover JSON request bodies. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you're using the `json()` method from `body-parser`, ie

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

---

While `"test"` is valid JSON, it's not very informative.

Try

```
contentType: 'application/json',
processData: false,
data: JSON.stringify({data: 'test'})
```

and in your route,

```
console.log('Route Test1:', req.body.data)
```

---

Another problem you're running in to is that you are automatically converting `req.body` into a string in your `console.log` calls due to the concatenation.

Instead, try

```
console.log('Route Test1:', req.body)
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding app.use(bodyParser.json()); to app.js and processData: false to the ajax call worked! Can I achieve the same functionality without adding the bodyParser line? Its fine to keep but just for my understanding.

Comment: @user2573690 do you want to post JSON requests to your app? If so, then you should use `bodyParser.json()`. Otherwise, you'll need to change your client-side code to post `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted data

Comment: Ah I see, I just did a read a bit more about bodyParser and it makes sense since I need to post JSON requests. Thanks for the help!